# Method to Encrypt the given string with the given number in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can anyone help me to write a method which takes 2 parameters (one string and one number). the method should return the string encrypted with the given number.

For Example:

My String: ABCDE
My Number: 3
Output Should Be: DEFGH

Note: String and Number are not constant.

Comment: More information needed. Should it handle both lowercase and uppercase? What should happen with whitespace and punctuation? What about non-ascii letters? What's the expected result for input 'Z', 1? Is it 'A', or maybe '['?

Comment: Thanks for the question. Actually this program is just to encrypt the given string so anything should be fine because if I reverse it, I should get my string back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = "ABCDE"
n = 3
s.chars.map{|ch| (ch.ord + n).chr}.join
# => "DEFGH"
```